# setRetainInstance not working for configuration changes in android

Tags: android

I have different design for potrait and landscape for activity.so i used layout-land layout .I put webview inside fragment and giving setRetainInstance(true) and loding url like google. when configuration changes it again loading can anybody tell how to avoid that .i didn't mention android:configchanges="orientation" in android manifestfile because 
different design can anybody help in this question?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments can actually make this a lot easier. Just use the method [Fragment.setRetainInstance(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) to have your fragment instance retained across configuration changes. Note that this is the recommended replacement for [Activity.onRetainnonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) in the docs.

If for some reason you really don't want to use a retained fragment, there are other approaches you can take. Note that each fragment has a unique identifier returned by [Fragment.getId().](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getId%28%29) You can also find out if a fragment is being torn down for a config change through
 [Fragment.getActivity().isChangingConfigurations()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isChangingConfigurations%28%29). So, at the point where you would decide to stop your AsyncTask (in onStop() or onDestroy() most likely), you could for example check if the configuration is changing and if so stick it in a static SparseArray under the fragment's identifier, and then in your onCreate() or onStart() look to see if you have an AsyncTask in the sparse array available.